# Create a linked table in Access from Teradata without DSN?

Tags: ms-access, database-connection, teradata

Connection to Teradata

```
'Requires reference to ADO and ADOX  
Public adoCn As ADODB.Connection
Public adoCat As New ADOX.Catalog
Public adoTbl As New ADOX.Table

Function TD_Make_Linked_Table()

Dim varServer As String
Dim varDatabase As String
Dim varUser As String
Dim varPassword As String

varServer = "Test"
varDatabase = "Test_Test"
varUser = "Test_User"
varPassword = "Test_Password"

Set adoCn = New ADODB.Connection

'I have tried multiple connection strings

adoCn.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;DRIVER={Teradata};" & _
                         "DBCName=" & varServer & ";" & _
                         "DefaultDatabase=" & varDatabase & ";" & _
                         "UID=" & varUser & ";" & _
                         "PWD=" & varPassword & ";"

adoCn.Open

Set adoCat = New ADOX.Catalog
Set adoCat.ActiveConnection = adoCn
Set adoTbl = New ADOX.Table

adoTbl.ParentCatalog = adoCat
adoTbl.Name = "Test"

'I have tried multiple property combinations
'Causes error 3265 Item not found
'adoTbl.Properties("?") = adoCn
'adoTbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Datasource") = "Test"
'adoTbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Provider String") = 
'adoTbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Remote Table Name") = "LinkDatabaseTable"
'adoTbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Create Link") = True

'Causes 3251 provider is not capable of performing operation
'adoCat.Tables.Append adoTbl

adoCn.Close

   Set adoTbl = Nothing
   Set adoCat = Nothing
   Set adoCn = Nothing

End Function
```

I have validated the connection is working. I can query data by opening the connection and executing SQL.

I am unable to create a linked table programmatically in Access using visual basic for applications with the created connection.

Has anyone been able to successfully create a linked dsn-less table from Access to Teradata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a connection string that works! :)

```vb
    Function adoTera()

        Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

        Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

        oConn.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;" & _
             "DRIVER={Teradata};" & _
             "DBCName=yourDBCName;" & _
             "DefaultDatabase=yourDBName;" & _
             "UID=yourUserName;" & _
             "PWD=yourPassword;"

        oConn.Open
        rs.Open "SELECT * FROM yourTable", oConn

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").CopyFromRecordset rs
        rs.Close
        oConn.Close

        Set rs = Nothing
        Set con = Nothing

    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a working ODBC connection string then you should be able to use [DoCmd.TransferDatabase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-transferdatabase-method-access) to create a linked table. I don't have a Teradata server handy, but this works for me with SQL Server:

```vbs
Dim connStr As String
connStr = _
        "DRIVER=ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server;" & _
        "SERVER=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
        "DATABASE=myDb;" & _
        "Trusted_Connection=yes"
DoCmd.TransferDatabase _
        TransferType:=acLink, _
        DatabaseType:="ODBC Database", _
        DatabaseName:="ODBC;" & connStr, _
        ObjectType:=acTable, _
        Source:="dbo.projects", _
        Destination:="dbo_projects"
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Teradata is not handling the request the same way. I receive Run-time error '3000' Reserved error (-7778); there is no message for this error.

Comment: @Orthogod - Are you able to manually create a linked table from within Access itself?

Comment: Yes, I am able to create a linked table to the data source from within Access.